# How to transfer file from remote server to local machine

Tags: ssh, scp

- I am on a Windows machine using Cygwin
- I want to connect to my raspberrypi and download a pdf from it called linuxnet.pdf
- I am a user named Zak

Here is what I have been doing which has not been working all day.

I can connect successfully,

- ssh pi@192.xxxx

The rest confuses me. This is what I am doing:

- `scp linuxnet.pdf zak@192.xxxx:linuxnet.pdf`

It then tells me it has downloaded, but I have no idea where it is. I would like to transfer it to the windows machine I am working at to dir `c:/users/docs`

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: I have called it 'server' as in 'john' or 'mark'

Comment: might be that destination should not include the filename itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What machine are you running this from and what OS is it using? Are you on your local machine or on the server? Where, exactly, is the copy created and on what machine? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Cygwin's default directory would be  the users home dir e.g C:\cygwin\home\zak\ . If you downloaded it with out specifying a path, its most likely there.

Answer (score 4):

This command

> ```
> scp linuxnet.pdf zak@192.xxxx:linuxnet.pdf
> ```

Copies the local file `linuxnet.pdf` to the remote server `192.xxxx`. It uses the user account `zak` and places the file in the remote user's home directory, named as `linuxnet.pdf`. Note that if `192.xxxx` represents your Pi then it will have placed the file in Zak's home directory.

You said that you wanted to copy *from* the remote server to your local Windows client. In this case you should reverse the order of the arguments thus, and run the command from Cygwin:

```
scp zak@192.xxxx:linuxnet.pdf linuxnet.pdf
```

The lack of directory specification on the target filename means that it will be written to the current directory, whatever that is at the time you execute the copy.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
According to the extra information you added, you are first connecting to the raspberry pi, and then using the `scp` executable present on the raspberry pi. This will only work if you have set up a ssh serveur on the Windows machine, and I would expect it to be easier to copy the file directly from the Windows machine.

To download using `scp` on the Windows machine, launch Cygwin but do not use the `ssh` command. Rather, go to the directory you want to download in, using the following command : `cd /cygdrive/c/path/that/you/like` (obviously replacing `c` by the relevant drive letter and `path/that/you/like` by the relevant path, but still using `/` rather than `\`). Then use `scp pi@192.xxxx:path/to/linuxnet.pdf .` (replacing `path/to/` by either the relative path from your home directory, or the absolute path). Alternatively, you can skip the first command and use `scp pi@192.xxxx:path/to/linuxnet.pdf /cygdrive/c/path/that/you/like` instead.